# Connection Refused: ssh to headless Raspberry Pi 3 b+

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have downloaded raspbian lite and flashed it to SD card through etcher

As per raspbian's headless ssh tutorial, I created an empty ssh file in /boot

`touch /Volumes/boot/ssh`

Then I connected ethernet cable from pi into apple airport extreme

when pi is booted, airport utility on macbook shows 10.0.1.9 as a new device on the network

from macbook:

`$ ssh -vvv pi@10.0.1.9
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.1.9 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.9 [10.0.1.9] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.1.9 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.0.1.9 port 22: Connection refused`

I've done this multiple times, recreating the ssh file at each boot, redownloading and reflashing the raspbian image, it always fails.
I'm 100% certain of 10.0.1.9 being the pi's local ip because i've attempted this around 10 times and it only appears when pi is on and ethernet is plugged in

Answer (score 2):

Run these command to generate the needed keys for ssh remote access.

sudo rm -r /etc/ssh/ssh*key

sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server